Sanity Check Streak of Head's
You have a biased coin with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ of heads. If you flip the coin 10 times, what is the probability of having 8 or more heads in a row?
I tried doing this question two ways, using PIE and without.
Without PIE, I broke it into three separate cases:
Exactly 8 in a row = $(\frac{1}{3})^{8}(\frac{2}{3})²$ (middle 8) and then $2(\frac{1}{3})^{8}(\frac{2}{3})$ (first 8, or last 8)
Exactly 9 in a row = $2\times(\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{3})^{9}$
Exactly 10 in a row = $(\frac{1}{3})^{10}$
This results in a total probability of $\frac{7}{19683}$.
With PIE, I consider the three events, ABC, with A being first 8, B being middle 8, C being last 8. And get the following:
$3\times(\frac{1}{3})^{8} - 2(\frac{1}{3})^{9} + (\frac{1}{3})^{10} = \frac{22}{59049}$.
Does someone mind sanity checking me?

I think in PIE you missed out "A and C" which would subtract another $(1/3)^{10}$.

As a check, these are the possible successful cases:

HHHHHHHHHH probability $1/3^{10}$
HHHHHHHHHT probability $2/3^{10}$
HHHHHHHHTH probability $2/3^{10}$
HHHHHHHHTT probability $4/3^{10}$
HTHHHHHHHH probability $2/3^{10}$
THHHHHHHHH probability $2/3^{10}$
THHHHHHHHT probability $4/3^{10}$
TTHHHHHHHH probability $4/3^{10}$

giving a total of $21/3^{10}$ which is your $\frac{7}{19683}$.
